# How can I uninstall Alkido 1.1 when both Alkido 2.0 and Alkido 1.1 are installed on my Samsung Galaxy S

Tags: uninstallation, ebook-reader

After installing my Archos 101 tablet, I noticed that the Alkido version I installed on it was version 2, when the version installed on my Galaxy S was still version 1.1.

The market when run on the Galaxy never told me there was an update.

**I just installed version 2.0 of Alkido on my Galaxy, resulting in both versions being installed.**

However, I find **no place where I can install version 1.1** !

- Settings - Applications - Running applications show both version 1.1 and version 2.0 ( cause I just started both programs ).
- Pressing version 1.1 does not give me an option to uninstall (e.g. the Uninstall button is greyed out)
- Settings - Applications - All show both version 1.1 and version 2.0
- Settings - Applications - Third-party only show version 2.0

Both programs have their own data folder so it seems, as I don't see the books visible in version 1.1 being displayed in version 2.0.

The market, as I said, only shows version 2.0.

**Any other place I can start an uninstall ?**

Comment: Grammar nazi, I may be...but isn't the app called Aldiko?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like Alkido 1.1 was bundled on your device as a system app.  To remove a system app, you need root.

There are two ways to address this easily, I would prefer #1 myself.

## Method 1

1. Uninstall Alkido 2.0.
2. Install [Titanium Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup).
3. Run Titanium and wait for it to load your app list.
4. Go to the app list and long-press on Alkido 1.1.
5. Choose "Integrate with Market" or similar.
6. Go to `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications`, find the Market, and clear the data for it.
7. Open the Market, go to your apps, and update Alkido.

If that doesn't work or you don't want to bother keeping Alkido as a system app:

## Method 2

1. Install Titanium.
2. Run Titanium, long-press on Alkido 1.1.
3. Choose "Uninstall" or similar.  You shouldn't need the "hack" version of uninstalling that it mentions, but you can try that if the regular uninstall doesn't work.

Alkido 2.0 will be unaffected if you didn't uninstall it in Method 1.